# AVR - Can't add Programmer on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, avr, avrdude

I want to use Eclipse to develop code I will be uploading to my Atmega 2560 microcontroller.  I could easily use the Arduino IDE to do this, but in my opinion, developing on Eclipse is a whole lot easier.

So, I followed [this](http://interactive-matter.eu/how-to/developing-software-for-the-atmel-avr-with-avr-eclipse-avr-gcc-avrdude/) guide.

I get to the step where I have to add a programmer, but when I click on the *Add* button, nothing happens.

Does anyone have an idea as to what might be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that 6.0.x series of avrdude uses a different configuration file which the avr-eclipse plugin is not able to parse. There is a ticket filed for this in the bug tracker in SourceForge.

A temporary solution would be to downgrade to avrdude 5.11.x.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use Eclipse for Arduino development and I followed this tutorial too but it didn't work for me. Also I couldn't find normal description of how I have to use it. From the other side so called Arduino IDE in my opinion isn't IDE it's very primitive buggy editor(looks like amateur product).

To upload my program to Atmega controller I decided to use avrdude direct from the console, where I specify programmer type and hex file that I want to upload. In this case I write program in c and use avrgcc toolchain for compiling and linking. However the question about IDE is still opened for me(the main problem for me that I don't know how to debug my code without IDE).

Also exist Atmel IDE AVrStudio. I didn'y try to use it, my I will mention it like a variant that you can try if you want.

Comment: I've just noticed that I didn't ask a real question, which leads to bad answers.  I greatly appreciate your quick response, but this is not what I was looking for, and it's entirely my fault.  I will rephrase my question to try and get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Getting AVRDude (used by the AVR-ecplipse plugin) running on Windows with USB connected AVR programmers can be a real pain, often involving very specific driver uninstall/install sequences, such as those described at the bottom of [this forum topic](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=468532). I used to use Eclipse for my AVR programming, but have since moved to the new iteration of [Atmel Studio](http://www.atmel.com/microsite/atmel_studio6/). Version 6 is now available, and its relatively straight forward to get everything working well. There are a few things odd about it, but it has improved a lot since AS4.