# Problems setting up an AVR MCU programmer in Eclipse 2024-03

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, avr, avrdude

I installed `Eclipse 2024-03` with the plugin to manage `AVR` MCUs. But when I try to indicate which MCU programmer I intend to use, using the `Windows->Preference->AVR` window, although I can see from the console window that the devices have been identified, I am not allowed to add them and therefore use them.

I use `Kali OS (Linux 5.15.44-Re4son-v8l+ #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian kali-pi (2022-07-03) aarch64 GNU/Linux)` on `Raspberry PI4`.

The `avrdude` (version 7.1) program works perfectly if launched from the command line. I can't understand why Eclipse is unable to configure any device starting from the configuration file `/etc/avrdude.conf` which however seems to find and manage (through the execution of avrdude).

I would simply to configure the device:
`usbasp` = USBasp, [/etc/avrdude.conf:1217]

Can anyone give me information on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the same problem with previous versions of `Eclipse`; the problem is not Eclipse, but the fact that the `AVR plugin` does not handle `avrdude 7.1`.

I solved it by following the stackoverflow post [AVR - Can't add Programmer on Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20418185/avr-cant-add-programmer-on-eclipse?rq=2).

Since I didn't like the solution of downgrading avrdude very much, I downloaed `avrdude 5.11.1` from https://download-mirror.savannah.gnu.org/releases/avrdude/avrdude-5.11.1.tar.gz and I compiled it in a local directory. Then I set the AVR configurations in Eclipse in a customized way so as to use avrdude 5.11 in Eclipse, but have avrdude 7.1 on the command line.

If you do not want to downgrade avrdude you must configure Eclipse using the `Windows->Preverence->AVR` menu by modifying the AVR path (in `AVR->Paths`) and pointing (in `AVR->AVRdude`) to the avrdude.conf file located in the local directory where you compiled avrdude 5.11 and so your problem is solved!